# How to remove space to the right and bottom of checkbox and radio-button in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, checkbox, radio-button

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MOBWeR

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="radio">
```

CSS:

```
input {
  outline: 1px solid;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You're lookign for `appearance` (and prefixes).

Comment: @panther: Thanks. But how does it help in removing the space?

Comment: What space you mean? Between both inputs? Or...? Probably misunderstood your question.

Comment: @panther: No the one to the right and bottom of each within the outline.

Comment: ah, okay. The real input size is what is outlined. The visible shape of checkbox/radio is a little bit smaller in your browser, but active (clickable) area is the same as outlined. Eg. in Safari/Mac the outline is the same size as elements are showed. There is no way how to prevent this.

Comment: @panther: Too bad. Its pretty ugly. So I might have to style those elements myself after all...

Comment: Do you need `outline`? If so, remove the default input style using `appearance` and set your own.

Comment: @panther: Still that means I have to take care of the other styling, like adding a check mark, as well, right?

Comment: Of course, Daniel.